# The multi-part identifier could not be bound using a linked server with ODBC connection to a DB2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

when I run this simple query

```
select [B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[SCTRN].[STCOMP], 
[EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[SCTRN].[STDATE],
[EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[SCTRN].[STUNM],
[EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[SCTRN].[STQTY] 
FROM [EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[SCTRN] 
WHERE [EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[SCTRN].[STCOMP]='51' 
AND [EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[SCTRN].[STDATE] = 20140211 
AND [EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[SCTRN].[STVOID] = 'N' 
ORDER BY [EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[SCTRN].[STTCKT]
```

in my sql I got the below errors

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "EPAK.B00BF4CR.IWSE4S8.SCTRN.STCOMP" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "EPAK.B00BF4CR.IWSE4S8.SCTRN.STDATE" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "EPAK.B00BF4CR.IWSE4S8.SCTRN.STVOID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "B00BF4CR.IWSE4S8.SCTRN.STCOMP" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "EPAK.B00BF4CR.IWSE4S8.SCTRN.STDATE" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "EPAK.B00BF4CR.IWSE4S8.SCTRN.STUNM" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "EPAK.B00BF4CR.IWSE4S8.SCTRN.STQTY" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The multi-part identifier "EPAK.B00BF4CR.IWSE4S8.SCTRN.STTCKT" could not be bound.
```

when I do double clic on the 1st one it highlight this section

```
FROM [EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[SCTRN] 
WHERE [EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[SCTRN].[STCOMP]='51' AND
```

the 2nd and the 3rd ones

```
[EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[SCTRN].[STDATE] = 20140211 
AND [EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[SCTRN].[STVOID] = 'N' ORDER BY
```

4, 5 and 6

```
select [B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[SCTRN].[STCOMP], 
[EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[SCTRN].[STDATE],
[EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[SCTRN].[STUNM],
```

7

```
[EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[SCTRN].[STQTY]
```

8

```
[EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[SCTRN].[STTCKT]
```

Comment: what is [B00BF4CR] and [IWSE4S8] and [SCTRN]?

Comment: this is the route [EPAK] is the server, [B00BF4CR] is something that goes below, then [IWSE4S8], [SCTRN] is the table name and [STTCKT] for example is a field that belongs to that table

Comment: what's the name of the linked server?, and you should try using `OPENQUERY` for this

Comment: the name of the linked server is EPAK

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At most, you can have a four part notation.  Your query is invalidating that rule for the column names.  A table alias comes in handy to avoid this issue.

[LINKEDSERVER].[DATABASE].[OWNER].[OBJECT]

Here is a rewrite of the query.

```
-- Use a table alias
SELECT
    S.[STCOMP], 
    S.[STDATE],
    S.[STUNM],
    S.[STQTY] 
FROM 
    [EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[SCTRN] AS S
WHERE
    S.[STCOMP]='51' AND
    S.[STDATE] = 20140211 AND
    S.[STVOID] = 'N' 
ORDER BY 
    S.[STTCKT]
```

There are some issues with updates and deletes using Distributed Query Processing (DQP) through DB2OLEDB.

See article below for warning about this as well as examples of pass thru query vs linked server.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222937

Comment: it seems to be working but for some reason is taking too long to bring the data

Comment: [Source Server - Computation Time] - Make sure there is an index for the three search columns.  Otherwise, it will do a full table scan. [Network Time] - How many rows are you expecting back and what is the network connectivity between the two systems.  Large number of rows over a small LAN/WAN pipe will take time.  [Alternatives] The other solution is to use an native DB2 tool do dump the source data to a ASCII file.  Pick up the file from AS400 or OS390 using FTP. Use SSIS to load flat file in the SQL Server target system.